# react native how to call multiple functions when onPress is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call multiple functions when I click `onPress` using `TouchableOpacity`

For example:

```
functionOne(){
// do something
}

functionTwo(){
// do someting
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress{() => this.functionOne()}/>
```

What if I want to call two functions when `onPress` is clicked? Is there a way I could call multiple functions?

Comment: make a handler that calls both

Comment: `onPress{() => { this.functionOne(); this.functionTwo();}}`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. but if I use it without an arrow function something like `onPress={{this.fucntionOne, thisfucntionTwo}}` this won't work.

Comment: yeah, but that's not what I wrote, so, not sure what you're even saying

Comment: @JaromandaX I was wondering if there is a way to use it without an arrow function.

Comment: no, because that would not work

Comment: @JaromandaX your comment worked for me when I added "=" to it, like so onPress={() => { this.functionOne(); this.functionTwo();}}

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. One option would be to define a function that calls `functionOne` and `functionTwo`, and pass that on your `onPress` handler like so:

```js
functionOne(){
// do something
}

functionTwo(){
// do something
}

functionCombined() {
    this.functionOne();
    this.functionTwo();
}  

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.functionCombined()}/>
```

Alternatively, and more concisely, you could express `functionCombined` inline in your JSX like so:

```js
functionOne(){
// do something
}

functionTwo(){
// do someting
}

<TouchableHighlight
 onPress={
  () => { this.functionOne(); this.functionTwo(); }
 }
/>
```

Comment: Can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567904/handle-call-functions-with-async-and-await

Answer (score 9):

Recommended Solution:

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
     function1();
     function2();
    }}>
```

You can use these props:

> **`onPress`** Called when the touch is released
>
> **`onPressIn`** Called as soon as the touchable element is pressed and invoked before `onPress`.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      function1();
    }}
    onPressIn={() => {
      function2();
    }}
 >
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call a function and then navigate to a screen, then do this way.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.onSubmit(); this.props.navigation.navigate('NextScreen') }}>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make this with a boolean value.
Example ;

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress{() => { this.functionOne() || this.functionTwo()}}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeking your comment, you want to not used arrow, so I'm suggest to use something like this:

```
functionOne(){
// do something
}

functionTwo(){
// do someting
}

mixFunction=()=>{
functionOne();
functionTwo();
}

mixFuncWithoutArrow(){
functionOne();
functionTwo();
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress{this.mixFunction() || this.mixFuncWithoutArrow.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: can you check this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567904/handle-call-functions-with-async-and-await

Answer (score 1):

This is an example and it works (from ELYES)

```
onPress={() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setTimeout(
        () =>  props.navigation.navigate("Login"),
        1000
    );
}}
```

Comment: "From ELYES" what do you mean with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple, we use just PLUS   '**+**'   between the functions :

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = {() => this.functionOne() + this.functionTwo() } />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also call the second method from this first one, like this way....

```
functionOne(){
 // do something
 functionTwo();
}

functionTwo(){
 // do someting
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress{() => this.functionOne()}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      functionA();
    }}
    onPressIn={() => {
      functionB();
    }}>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button 
onPress={() =>{
onIncrease();
show();
}}
 title={`Increase ${color}`}
/>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you add a little clarification around the answer? Thank you!