# How to call one of multiple functions - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I have three functions:

1. Change Email
2. Change password
3. Change otherData

And One Button to call them ,
when the user changes his data without change Email Or Password I don't wont to call other function **Change Email or Change Password** just call the function Change other data, and when changing his email with other data like username, location I just want to call **Change Email, change other data Function** NOT *Change Password*

So how to handle this, and how to get a current password and save them in my state cuz when I wrote the wrong password, change Other Data function execute?

I'm using Firebase as a backend

#### Edit Screen

[image: Edit Screen]

#### here is my code **[React Native App]**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import styles from "../Style/styles";

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import {
    View,
    Text,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    StyleSheet,
    ActivityIndicator,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';


class profileEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPassword: "",
            newPassword: "",
            currentUser: {
                username: "",
                email: "",
                city: "",
                mobileNumber: "",
            },
            data: {},
            loading: true
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            await this.setState({ userId });
            console.log("@uid", this.state.userId);
            let recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);
            await recentPostsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
                this.setState({ currentUser: snapshot.val(), loading: false })
                console.log(this.state.currentUser)
            }).catch((error) => console.log("@error", error));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("@CError", error);
        }
    }

    reauthenticate = (currentPassword) => {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
            user.email, currentPassword);
        return user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred);
    }

    _updateProfileData = async () => {
        if (this.state.currentPassword === "") {
            alert("please write your current password first!")
            return;
        } else {
            await this._updateData();
            await this.changeEmail();
            await this.changePassword();
        }
    }
    changePassword = () => {
        if (this.state.currentPassword === "" || this.state.newPassword === "") {
            return
        } else {
            this.reauthenticate(this.state.currentPassword).then(() => {
                var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                user.updatePassword(this.state.newPassword).then(() => {
                    console.log("Pssword updated!");
                    this._updateData();
                    this.setState({ newPassword: "", currentPassword: "" });
                }).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
        }
    }
    changeEmail = () => {
        this.reauthenticate(this.state.currentPassword).then(() => {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            user.updateEmail(this.state.currentUser.email).then(() => {
                console.log("Email updated!");
                this._updateData();
            }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
        }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
    }
    _updateData = () => {
        const { userId, currentUser } = this.state;
        let recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);
        recentPostsRef.update({
            username: currentUser.username,
            email: currentUser.email,
            city: currentUser.city,
            mobileNumber: currentUser.mobileNumber,
        }).then(async () => {
            let Data = await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('@MyProfile:data', JSON.stringify(currentUser))
            console.log(Data)
            alert("Great, your profile updated right now!")
        }).then(async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyProfile:data')
                .then(json => JSON.parse(json))
                .then(currentUser => this.setState({ currentUser }))
                .catch(error => console.log('@error' + error));
        })
    }
    // _logout = () => {
    //     firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    //         alert("Logout successfuly")
    //         setTimeout(() => {
    //             this.props.navigation.navigate("SignIn")
    //         }, 500)
    //     }).catch((error) => console.log("@error", error));
    // }

    render() {
        const { currentUser, loading } = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return (
                <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text>Just a moment.</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#1567d3" />
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            console.log("Loading False");
            return (
                <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true}>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={70}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <View style={styles.logoSection}>
                                {/* <SvgComponent height={100} /> */}
                                <Icon name="ios-contact" size={90} color='#4d8dd6' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />

                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: "#000", margin: 35, marginTop: 7 }}>
                                    {currentUser.username}
                                </Text>
                            </View>

                            {/* //username */}
                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="ios-contact" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    value={currentUser.username}
                                    onChangeText={(username) => { this.setState(Object.assign(currentUser, { username: username })) }}
                                />
                            </View>

                            {/* //Email */}
                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="md-at" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    keyboardType="email-address"
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    value={currentUser.email}
                                    onChangeText={
                                        (email) => { this.setState(Object.assign(currentUser, { email: email })) }
                                    }
                                />
                            </View>

                            {/* //Password */}

                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="md-lock" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    placeholder="current password"
                                    value={this.state.currentPassword}
                                    onChangeText={(currentPassword) => this.setState({ currentPassword })}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="md-lock" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    placeholder="New password"
                                    value={this.state.newPassword}
                                    onChangeText={(newPassword) => { this.setState({ newPassword }) }}
                                />
                            </View>

                            {/* //Location */}
                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="ios-navigate" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    placeholder="New City"
                                    value={currentUser.city}
                                    onChangeText={(city) => { this.setState(Object.assign(currentUser, { city: city })) }}
                                />
                            </View>

                            <View style={style.child}>
                                <Icon name="ios-call" size={30} color='#4285f4' style={{ marginTop: 9 }} />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={style.textInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="words"
                                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                                    placeholder="New Mobile Number"
                                    value={currentUser.mobileNumber}
                                    onChangeText={(mobileNumber) => { this.setState(Object.assign(currentUser, { mobileNumber: mobileNumber })) }}
                                />
                            </View>

                            {/* Logout 
                            <TouchableOpacity style={style.logout} onPress={this._logout}>
                                <Icon name="md-power" size={25} color='#0496FF' style={{ marginTop: -2 }} />
                                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>Logout</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            */}
                        </View>

                        {/* Save */}
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._updateProfileData}
                            style={[styles.button, style.saveBtn]}>
                            <Text style={styles.TextButton}>Save</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default profileEdit;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need an `if`/`else`? [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: I don't understand - how is it possible for the user to change more than a single field at a given moment? Do you have a submit button, or are you making the API call using the `onChange`?

Comment: It looks like React code because you using state. If so, provide all of the code. In general - you should change only the state on user changes/actions, and after state changes - depending on the state you are firing action you need

Comment: @Kirill , check again, I'm adding all of my code

Comment: @crashmstr check again, I'm adding all of my code

Comment: @YoavKadosh check again, I'm adding all of my code

Comment: Your added code does not affect my suggestion that you should perhaps use if...else to check conditions and conditionally execute the functions you need to based on those conditions.

Comment: @crashmstr yup i see, check the Bottom Answer

Comment: @crashmstr any help ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you are needing?

Is it that when you update *one* field you don't want any other fields to re-render?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Not Exactly, now I'm writing a seprate function for Email and Password as you see in my code and I have One Button to Change these data and other data "city, the mobile number", so I'm confused, because when I want to change lets say City I don't need to call Change Email function ! and so on

Comment: other = `username`, `city` and `mobileNumber`?

Comment: @JuniusL. Yes it's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options, option add more variables to state which you can use to compare the new data with and option two use three boolean values, one for password, email and other.

**Option 1**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    currentPassword: "",
    newPassword: "",
    email: '',
    currentUser: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      city: "",
      mobileNumber: "",
    },
    username: '',
    city: '',
    mobileNumber: '',
    data: {},
    loading: true
  }
}

_updateProfileData = async () => {

  const { currentPassword, email, currentUser, newPassword,
    mobileNumber, username, city } = this.state;

  if (currentPassword === "") {
    alert("please write your current password first!")
    return;
  }

  if (email !== currentUser.email) {
    // email changed update
    await this.changeEmail();
  }

  if (newPassword !== currentPassword) {
    // password changed update
    await this.changePassword();
  }

  if (city !== currentUser.city || mobileNumber !== currentUser.mobileNumber || username !== currentUser.username) {
    await this._updateData();
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    await this.setState({ userId });
    console.log("@uid", this.state.userId);
    let recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);
    await recentPostsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const currentUser = snapshot.val();
      this.setState({ currentUser: currentUser, email: currentUser.email, username: currentUser.username, city: currentUser.city, mobileNumber: currentUser.mobileNumber, loading: false })
      console.log(this.state.currentUser)
    }).catch((error) => console.log("@error", error));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("@CError", error);
  }
}
```

**Option 2**, have three booleans, `passwordChanged,emailChanged,otherChanged` when the user types in one of the inputs, set the value to true and in your `_updateProfileData` check if the value is true, then update the value.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    currentPassword: "",
    newPassword: "",
    currentUser: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      city: "",
      mobileNumber: "",
    },
    data: {},
    // boolean values for email, password and other
    passwordChanged: false,
    emailChanged: false,
    otherChanged: false,
    loading: true
  }
}

_updateProfileData = async () => {

  const { currentPassword, passwordChanged, emailChanged, otherChanged } = this.state;

  if (currentPassword === "") {
    alert("please write your current password first!")
    return;
  }

  if (emailChanged) {
    // email changed update
    await this.changeEmail();
  }

  if (passwordChanged) {
    // password changed update
    await this.changePassword();
  }

  if (otherChanged) {
    await this._updateData();
  }
}
```

Comment: when I use Option Two, I can't see any action when changing any of "other data, email, password"  and click to button **_updateProfileData**

Comment: did you set the flag in state?

Comment: sorry but what did you mean of flag?

Comment: `otherChanged: true`

Comment: yup, work just with otherData function, Change Email, Password Never!

Answer (score -2):

Please do the following:

```
// You have to change the method _updateProfileData as following
_updateProfileData = async () => {
        if (this.state.currentPassword === "") {
            alert("please write your current password first!")
            return;
        } if (this.state.currentUser.email === "") {
            alert("Email can't be blank")
            return;
        } if (this.state.currentUser.username === "") {
            alert("Username can't be blank")
            return;
        } if (this.state.currentUser.city === "") {
            alert("City can't be blank")
            return;
        } if (this.state.currentUser.mobileNumber === "") {
            alert("Mobile number can't be blank")
            return;
        } else {
            this._getCurrentUserData((oldUserData) => {
            if(oldUserData.email !== this.state.currentUser.email) {
                 await this.changeEmail();
            }

            if(this.state.newPassword !== this.state.currentPassword) {
                 await this.changePassword();
            }

            if(oldUserData.username !== this.state.currentUser.username || oldUserData.city !== this.state.currentUser.city || oldUserData.mobileNumber !== this.state.currentUser.mobileNumber ) {
                 await this._updateData();
            }
            );
        }
    }

// You have to add this method in your component
_getCurrentUserData = (callBack) => {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyProfile:data')
            .then(json => JSON.parse(json))
            .then(currentUser => callBack(currentUser))
            .catch(error => console.log('@error' + error));
}
```

Comment: when just change City Field I see in console the change email function is calling "Email updated!"

Comment: No, if you will change the email then only it will execute the email update function. I'm sure. Could you please add a console to print oldUserData.email and  this.state.currentUser.email while you are updating the city only?

Comment: oldUserData.email => undefined,
 this.state.currentUser.email =>devas@gmail.com

Comment: and when i write the wrong password _updateData function invoked!

Comment: Try it now, I updated the code. Please add validation for wrong password prevention.