# Can't Re-render FlatList after deleting last item Although use extraData - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I'm tried to re-render Flat list but can't be updated anymore,

I'm getting the data from real-time DB and passed to Flatlist as a data props,
and write a function to delete an item from the list and DB and work very well, but when I delete the last one of the list  I can not see Empty screen "List" just stock with the last one I've deleted Although it's deleted in DB!

### code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

class UserFavorites extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentUser: null,
            favorites: [],

        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        this.setState({ currentUser });
        const favorites = firebase.database().ref(`favorites/${currentUser}`);
        favorites.on("value", (snapshot) => {
            let favorites = []
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                favorites.push({
                    ProviderId: childSnapshot.val().ProviderId,
                    providerName: childSnapshot.val().providerName,
                    providerService: childSnapshot.val().providerService,
                });
                this.setState({ favorites })
            });
        });
    }
    _listEmptyComponent = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}> No favorites Provider Found :O</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    render() {
        const { fav } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <FlatList data={this.state.favorites}
                    key={Math.random() * 1000}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent()}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return (
                            <ScrollView>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            flex: 1,
                                            paddingLeft: 15,
                                            paddingRight: 10,
                                            height: 105,
                                            alignItems: "center",
                                            backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                                            flexDirection: "row",
                                            borderBottomWidth: .8,
                                            borderBottomColor: "#aaa"
                                        }}>
                                        <Icon style={{ alignSelf: "center" }} name="ios-contact" size={60} color="#1567d3" />
                                        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 5, flexDirection: "row" }}>
                                            <View style={{ marginLeft: 27 }}>
                                                <Text style={{
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    fontWeight: "800",
                                                    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
                                                    color: '#000',
                                                }}>
                                                    {item.providerName}
                                                </Text>
                                                <Text style={{
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    fontWeight: "800",
                                                    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
                                                    color: '#000',
                                                }}>
                                                    {item.providerService}

                                                </Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}>
                                                <Icon style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                                                    name={`ios-heart${fav ? "" : "-empty"}`}
                                                    size={35} color="#f00"
                                                    onPress={() => {
                                                        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                                                        firebase.database().ref(`favorites/${currentUser}/${item.ProviderId}`).remove().then(() => alert("Removed"))
                                                    }}
                                                />
                                            </View>

                                        </View>

                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </ScrollView>
                        )
                    }
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});

export default UserFavorites;
```

Comment: I think you are only removing from  firebase but not from `favorites`.

Comment: @JuniusL. but other items deleted and I see it disappear

Comment: In that Icon onPress function try also updating this.state.favorites. This is what the FlatList is using for its data so this is the array that needs to be updated anytime you want to see rows added/removed.

Comment: @RichardMcCluskey updating with what? this.setStat({favorites: ? }) !

Comment: @JuniusL. when I use filter() to delete one of the items all list deleted how to handle this to delete just what i pressed? `_onRemove = (_item) => {
        this.setState({
            favorites: this.state.favorites.filter(item => item.id === _item)
        });
        console.log(this.state.favorites)}`

Comment: you forgot an id, `filter(item => item.id === _item.id)`

Comment: @JuniusL. yup, but I didn't see any actions for deleted this item, the log of `this.state.favorites` is an Array of objects  length 5

Comment: @JuniusL. https://imgur.com/k4MOB7R

Comment: please share your code here https://codeshare.io/an7Erv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the item from firebase but not from the flatlist's data source `this.state.favorites`, add a function that'll you call after removing the item from firebase.

```
_onRemove = (_item) => { 

   this.setState({ 
     favorites: this.state.favorites.filter(item => item.ProviderId !== _item.ProviderId) 
   });
}
```

Pass the item you want to delete to the function in your flatlist

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {
  return ....
   //scrollview code
   <Icon style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
    name={`ios-heart${fav ? "" : "-empty"}`}
    size={35} color="#f00"
    onPress={() => {
       const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
       ....
       // firebase code
       this._onRemove(item);
    }
   />
  ....
  //rest of the code
}}
```

Comment: @JunisL. Hey again, if you have time can you check this answer ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567904/how-to-call-one-of-multiple-functions-javascript